# Facebook Oauth and sending messages to facebook users

Tags: 7, social-network

I have Facebook OAuth and Facebook Connect installed on a site. We need to be able to periodically send a message to one of our member's Facebook inbox who logged in with the Facebook Connect.  I've looked all over, and haven't had much luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user registers or connects with his/her Facebook account, your web application receives that person's Facebook username which you can then store in a field.

On Facebook, you can receive external messages at username@facebook.com.

Now all that's left to for you to do is set up Rules module (maybe Facebook Rules module can help) so that if a user has connected his account on your website with his Facebook account an email is sent to username@facebook.com.

Comment: There is no authentication on their side, i.e., anyone can send an email to a facebook user?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I see.  And the messages in their inbox look like one of their friends messaged them?

Comment: Yes. If you have a Facebook account, you should try it out yourself. Send an email from any email address to your username@facebook.com

Comment: I gave in and set up an account.  Yeah, it worked as you said.  Thanks for the help!